# Google Cloud Compute engine - SQL Web 2017 missing ssis install

Tags: sql-server, ssis, google-compute-engine

please help me out.

Trying to install feature integration services on VM MS 2019 SQL 2017 web edition server, but it is missing the install files. According to Google SSIS is to be included in web edition licence..

If not, how do I then upgrade my SQL edition..

Best
/Peter

Comment: [Integration Services features supported by the editions of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Notice the lack of any "yes" options on this page for Web apart from the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

As the above comment mentions, the integration services are not available for the web addition. Currently, there is no way to upgrade to another OS version within GCP. You will have to create a new GCE VM instance and choose the proper OS image to use.